# PHP удаление тегов

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте добрые люди, не судите строго за детский вопрос, я только учусь. В PHP есть функция strip_tags, которая удаляет html теги в строке. Во втором ее параметре можно указать исключения, т.е. те теги которые она должно оставить, например вот так:

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<i><u><b>');
```

Вопрос; можно ли наоборот, указать в функции те параметры, которая она должна удалить, а все остальное оставить? Например

```
функция($text,<a>) //удалить теги <a> а все остальные оставить
```

Не обязательно именно strip_tags(), можно предложить и аналог. Регулярное выражение составить могу, но может есть специальная функция?

Comment: Такой функции нет, только писать аналог или использовать регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так же обойтись без использования сторонних библиотек. Эта функция будет удалять теги, переданные на её вход вторым параметром. Можно передавать более одного тега, разделяя их запятой *(можно с пробелом или без него)*.

**Примеры использования:**

```
// Удалить только теги "a" (текст тега останется)
echo del_tags($text, 'a');

// Удалить теги "a" и "br"
echo del_tags($text, 'a,br');

// Или с пробелами между именами тегов
echo del_tags($text, 'a, br'); // и т.д.


function del_tags($txt, $tag) {
    $tags = explode(',', $tag);

    do {
        $tag = array_shift($tags);
        $txt = preg_replace("~<($tag)[^>]*>|(?:</(?1)>)|<$tag\s?/?>~x", '', $txt);
    } while (!empty($tags));

    return $txt;
}
```

> [Демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28dae0b5a2a400d9ada915f161993f56dcb0a8a7)

Comment: @Игорь Саламов Текущая реализация удаляет **только** теги .Если не нужно оставлять текст между тегами *(например)* `<a>текст</a>`, то я подправлю шаблон.

Answer (score 2):

Можете воспользоваться библиотекой [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Работает она не очень быстро, но свое дело делает, пример конфига для вашего случая:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', ['a']); // Разрешаем только тег a
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', ['a.href']); // Разрешает использовать только атрибут href у тега a
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clear_text = $purifier->purify($text);
```

Возможностей у него очень много, можете почитать на досуге, возможно есть где то и русское описание.